# Called React-Redux action in prop does not give needed results

Tags: react-redux

I am implementing a component that handles an redux action to add comments but it is not working.No error is generated

I have tried calling the props from other regions in the code but that doesnt seem to work.The addComment Action should add the comments rendered in the DishDetails comments section.However no additions are made.

ActionTypes.js

```
export const ADD_COMMENT='ADD_COMMENT';
```

ActionCreators.js

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';


export const addComment=(dishId,rating, author, comment)=>({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload: {
        dishId:dishId,
        rating:rating,
        author:author,
        comment:comment
    }
});
```

comments.js

```
import { COMMENTS } from '../shared/comments';
import * as ActionTypes  from './ActionTypes';

export const Comments= (state= COMMENTS, action) => {
    switch(action.type){

        case ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT:
            var comment= action.payload;
            comment.id= state.length;
            comment.date = new Date().toISOString();
            return state.concat(comment);

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishDetail';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {addComment} from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  return{
    dishes: state.dishes,
    comments: state.comments,
    promotions: state.promotions,
    leaders: state.leaders
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addComment: (dishId,rating, author, comment)=>dispatch(addComment(dishId,rating, author, comment))
});

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const HomePage= ()=>{
      return(
        <Home dish={this.props.dishes.filter((dish)=>dish.featured)[0]}
              promotion={this.props.promotions.filter((promotion)=>promotion.featured)[0]}
              leader={this.props.leaders.filter((leader)=>leader.featured)[0]}
              />
      );
    }

    const DishWithId = ({match})=>{
      return(
        <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.filter((dish)=>dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))[0]}
                    comments={this.props.comments.filter((comment)=>comment.dishId=== parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))}
                    addComment={this.props.addComment}/>
      );
    }

    const AboutPage = ()=>{
      return(
        <About leaders={this.props.leaders}/>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
       <Header/> 
       <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
          <Route exact path="/menu" component={()=><Menu dishes ={this.props.dishes} />} />
          <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId}/>
          <Route exact path="/aboutus" component={() => <AboutPage leaders={this.props.leaders} />} />}/>
          <Route exact path="/contactus" component={Contact}/>
          <Redirect to="/home"/>
       </Switch>
       <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

DishDetail.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem , Button, Modal, ModalHeader,ModalBody, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import {Control, LocalForm, Errors} from 'react-redux-form';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const required = (val) =>val && val.length;
const maxLength = (len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len);
const minLength = (len) => (val) => val && (val.length >= len);

class DishDetail extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            dish:props.dish,


            isCommentModalOpen: false,

        };


        this.toggleCommentModal=this.toggleCommentModal.bind(this);

    }

    toggleCommentModal(){
        this.setState({
            isCommentModalOpen:!this.state.isCommentModalOpen
        });

    }

    handleSubmit(props,values){

        alert("State" + JSON.stringify(props.addComment(props.dishId, values.rating, values.author, values.comment)));
        // this.state.addComment(this.state.dishId, values.rating, values.author, values.comment)

    }

   render(){
    const RenderDish=({dish})=>{
        return(
                         <Card>

                            <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                            <CardBody>
                                <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                                <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                            </CardBody>
                        </Card>
        );
    }


         const RenderComments=({comments})=>{
            const comment_layout= comments.map((comment)=>{
                if(comment.comment!=null){
                   return(
                       <div>

                                    {comment.comment}
                                    {comment.author}, {new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))} 

                        </div>   
                   );             

                }else{
                    return(
                        <div></div>
                    );
                }

            });

            return(comment_layout);

        }

         const CommentForm=()=>{
            return(

                    <Button outline onClick={this.toggleCommentModal}>
                            <span className="fa fa-edit fa-lg">Submit Comment</span>
                    </Button>


            );

        }

        if (this.state.dish!==undefined){
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
            <Breadcrumb>

                <BreadcrumbItem>
                    <Link to="/menu">Menu</Link>
                </BreadcrumbItem>
                <BreadcrumbItem active>{this.state.dish.name}
                </BreadcrumbItem>
            </Breadcrumb>
            <div className="col-12">
                <h3>{this.state.dish.name}</h3>
                <hr/>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div className="row ">
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <RenderDish dish={this.state.dish}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-12 m-1">
                    <h4>Comment</h4>
                        <RenderComments comments={this.props.comments}
                         />
                         <CommentForm/>


                </div>
            </div>
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.isCommentModalOpen} toggle={this.toggleCommentModal}>
                <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleCommentModal}>
                  Submit Comment                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                <div className="col-12">
                        <LocalForm onSubmit={(values)=>this.handleSubmit(this.props,values)}>
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor ="rating" md={2}>Rating</Label>

                                    <Control.select model=".rating" id="rating" name="rating" className="form-control">
                                            <option value="1">1</option>
                                            <option value="2">2</option>
                                            <option value="3">3</option>
                                            <option value="4">4</option>
                                            <option value="5">5</option>
                                            <option value="6">6</option>
                                    </Control.select>


                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor ="name" md={2}>Name</Label>

                                    <Control.text  model=".name" className="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" validators={{required,minLength: minLength(3),maxLength:maxLength(15)}} />
                                    <Errors className="text-danger"
                                    model=".name"
                                    show="touched"
                                    messages={{
                                        required:'Required',
                                        minLength:'Must be greater than 2 char',
                                        maxLength: 'Must be 15 chars or less'
                                    }}
                                    />

                            </Row>

                           <Row className="form-group">
                                <Label htmlFor ="feedback" md={2}>Comment</Label>

                                    <Control.textarea model=".message" className="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="12" />


                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-group">

                                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>

                            </Row>
                        </LocalForm>
                    </div>

                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
            </div>


        );
        }else{
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
        }

}
}

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Can you please look at my answer and mark it as correct if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

you are not dispatching to the reducer in the action. Do it like this

```
export const addComment = (dishId, rating, author, comment) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
      payload: {
        dishId: dishId,
        rating: rating,
        author: author,
        comment: comment
      }
    })

  }
};
```